# Request/Creating a Code Signing Certificate

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, digital-signature

I have a need for a code signing certificate which is trusted by a CA in the Windows domain. How do I request/create this certificate?

Do I have to request a code signing certificate on the certificate server? I do not have access to this server myself and want to know if this is the only option. I believe that you have to enable the code signing template before you can request a certificate that can be used to sign code (in my situation an InfoPath form). Is this correct?

I'm also wondering about the possibility to create a self-signed certificate and make this trusted by the CA on the certificate server. Is this possible and considered good practice?

And a bit more practical, can you request a code signing certificate from a CA certificate on a client environment? If this is possible I assume you need to possess both private and public keys?

Comment: Your question seems to be based on a lot of unstated context. For example, you say "the certificate server". Umm, *what* certificate server are you talking about? When you say "CA", do you mean your own internal CA? Or are you talking about a public CA? And what does it mean to "request" a certificate "from a CA certificate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many code signing implementations will provide a way to sign the code using a system involving a pair of keys, one public and one private, similar to the process employed by SSL or SSH. For example, in the case of .NET, the developer uses a private key to sign their libraries or executables each time they build. This key will be unique to a developer or group or sometimes per application or object. The developer can either generate this key on their own or obtain one from a trusted certificate authority (CA).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you are wondering, but as far as I know, you have to download the code signing certificate to each computer that you want to use it on.

The only way to get a trusted certificate is through a Certificate Authority.

Then you can sign the code using [Microsoft's SignTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).